# Javascript Table Cell mouseover()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouseover

I have a table mytable1 contains 3-rows and td elements. The below code working fine when I have 6-rows. But when I have 3 rows it's not working. Any guidences will be helpful.

Note : The below code used, When the user mouseover the table images, the cursor will change.

My Codes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytable1 tr:has(td)").mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable1" table-layout="fixed" width="100%" style="margin-top: 0px; float:top;"> 
      <tr>
         <td><span>Design Code : A0001</span></td>
         <td><span>Design Code : A0002</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a><img src="Images/Img1.jpg"></a></td>
         <td><a><img src="Images/Img2.jpg"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><span>Colour : Wite</span></td>
         <td><span>Colour : Red</span></td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: What's the point of using mouseover instead of a normal CSS rule?

Comment: This seems to work in the snippet you provided. What is your question? However, this is not how to use the css-properties. First of all, You can just set `cursor: pointer;` and you are done: The mouse-pointer will change to a hand symbol on hover (even without using the pseudo-class). Second, that css-property is set permanently and will not be unset on mouse-leave.

Comment: Thanks Lupz. The confusion is when I have 6-rows, the above code working good. But when I have 3-rows like the above, it;s not working...

Comment: There are 3 rows in the code of your question. It seems to be working fine. What do you expect that script to do?

Comment: nope, it's not working

Comment: You need to be more specific than "not working". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? When you click on the "Run code snippet" button in your question, does the code not behave the way that you expected?

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working fine for what you want. Run the snippets below.

6 row example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytable1 tr:has(td)").mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable1" table-layout="fixed" width="100%" style="margin-top: 0px; float:top;"> 
      <tr>
         <td><span>Design Code : A0001</span></td>
         <td><span>Design Code : A0002</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a><img src="Images/Img1.jpg"></a></td>
         <td><a><img src="Images/Img2.jpg"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><span>Colour : White</span></td>
         <td><span>Colour : Red</span></td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
         <td><span>Design Code : A0001</span></td>
         <td><span>Design Code : A0002</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a><img src="Images/Img1.jpg"></a></td>
         <td><a><img src="Images/Img2.jpg"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><span>Colour : White</span></td>
         <td><span>Colour : Red</span></td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

3 row example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytable1 tr:has(td)").mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable1" table-layout="fixed" width="100%" style="margin-top: 0px; float:top;"> 
      <tr>
         <td><span>Design Code : A0001</span></td>
         <td><span>Design Code : A0002</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a><img src="Images/Img1.jpg"></a></td>
         <td><a><img src="Images/Img2.jpg"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><span>Colour : Wite</span></td>
         <td><span>Colour : Red</span></td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```